# Visual Studio Template Parameters: Machine Name Capitalized?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

[MSDN Template Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa%28VS.80%29.aspx)

**Is `$machinename$` always capitalized?** I wanted to write some code based on this return value, but Python's `socket.gethostname()` returns "Mark-PC" whereas `$machinename$` returns "MARK-PC". If so, I'll just `.upper()` the hostname, but it seems kinda dumb that I should have to do this. Why the inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that $machinename$ returns the NetBIOS name, and socket.gethostname() returns the host name.  They are different things even though Windows usually names them identically.  The host name API can technically return a different result if you change the Primary DNS suffix in your Windows system settings. (At which point it will be machine name + the suffix)

This is system level and not specific to python as illustrated by the equivalent C# APIs:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()  --> method would return Mark-PC
Environment.MachineName    --> property would return MARK-PC
```